# Keep the latest combobox selection when re-opening the application

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB.Net Visual Studio application.  If I select say value "B" from a combobox and then close the application, when I re-open it I want that combobox to have the latest choice selected before closing the app to be selected.  How do I do that?  Thank you.

Comment: You can store the last value (a value that can applied to the ComboBox `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem`), to a Setting of your Project. The UI Platform is important (here, I'm assuming WinForms, but it may be not): add the appropriate Tags to your question.

Comment: _VB.Net Visual Studio application_ - can be console, winforms, WPF or web application and all of them can have different techniques to store data outside of the application runtime. Which one you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Project Properties select Settings.
Set the Name, Type, Scope and Value as shown below.
[image]

I use the SelectedIndex so if nothing is selected, it will still work with -1.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = My.Settings.ComboSelection
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    My.Settings.ComboSelection = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Psst...Mary...you need to SAVE the settings!  `My.Settings.Save()`

Comment: @Idle_Mind Maybe it is because it is scoped to User but it seems to work without saving explicitly. Just the assignment in the Form.Closing does the trick.

Comment: Huh...I stand corrected.  I've always just saved the settings explicitly, which is apparently redundant, but only because the "Save My.Settings on Shutdown" option in Project --> Properties is turned ON by default.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I checked and I do have that on.

Comment: If you port the code over to a standard C# Winforms app, you have to include `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` to make it work.  VB.Net does have some nice default features.  ;)

Comment: There's no need for any code at all. You can bind the property to the setting in the Properties window for the control. You can even create the setting from there. It's under the `(ApplicationSettings)` node.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't see Selected  anything (Item, Value, or Index) in ApplicationSettings. I am being dense again.

Comment: There's only a small number of properties, if any, listed by default. You expand the `(ApplicationSettings)` node, select `(PropertyBinding)`, click the browse (...) button and you'll get a dialogue with all bindable properties. You can select a property and then select an existing setting or create a new one.

Comment: Hmmm... just did that and realised that you were probably already doing that because I don't see any `Selected...` properties listed either. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I realise now that those properties are not listed because binding them would mean their being set before the code that bound a data source and thus the selection would be invalid when it was set. It would appear that you do indeed require code for such properties, to ensure that they are set only after data has been bound. Makes sense now I think about it. As you were.